# line passing through a triangulated mesh (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, interpolation, mesh, spline, data-fitting

I have a triangulated mesh (as in the figure) and I would like to found the line passing trhough the points (see figure). i tried by a 2D fit but I lose the shape of the mesh.
Can someone suggest a method to obtain a line as that I drown by hand?[image]

Comment: Creating (and [edit]ing your question to include) a [mcve] would make this significantly easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an actual 3D path or mesh to work with, I have simulated one and show you how to use 3D splines for interpolation:

```
% simulating a 3D path and plotting it
N = 1000;
rng(1);
xyz = cumsum([randn(N,1)+0.8, randn(N,1)+0.2, randn(N,1)*2]);
plot3(xyz(:,1),xyz(:,2),xyz(:,3),'-b','LineWidth',2);
box on; view(30,30);

% interpolating using 3D splines.
% "smoothness" determines how many points to skip.
smoothness = floor( N/30 );
hold on;
fnplt(cscvn(xyz(1:smoothness:end,:)'),'r',2);
hold off;
```

Here is what the result shows (the original path is blue, the interpolated path is red):
[image]

Comment: many thanks, actually I have to work with a mesh. If I apply your method to my data I obtain the following; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sY5-PgntEarrYUnL-gF3YX3IdDwuyp-M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here you can fin my actual data:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gn6Un65GvTk2SzHWIO3buouhs6T8pjMk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: xyz = unique( solco_near_scalpo.vertices, 'rows' );